# I uploaded snap on snapcraft now how can i delete this?

Tags: linux, electron, electron-builder, snapcraft

Hello Guys I had created a useless app to test distributions of the app on different platforms.

now I want to remove that from the snap store how can I?

i published it by uding `snapcraft upload --release=stable updatelearning_xxx_amd64.snap`[image]

How to delete this?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the go-to place for such issues, I would say. Why not try [snapcraft.io's forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io)? There's [this article](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/remove-snap-from-store/6229) on your very probolem.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete your snap if it has not be download by anyone. If this is the case a trash can icon will appear by the title. If it has been download you will need to [file a issue here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapstore/) to have it deleted.

Information from [this forum.snapcraft.io thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-delete-snap/1590).

If you just want to pause a snaps distribution until a later time, you can close all channels, effectively making in unavailable.

To make it so that the snap is not found by searches on the snap store, change its status to anything but public.